# How to download a file from URL using Alamofire to a custom folder

Tags: swift, file, download, alamofire

[image]I'm using Alamofire to a download file from url, I'm getting filepath, but I'm not able to track down that filepath

```
let mjString = "https://wallpaperstock.net/wallpapers/thumbs1/42535.jpg" 
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

    print("destinationURLForFile ***********    \(documentsURL)")
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("42535.jpg")
    return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}

Alamofire.download(mjString, to: destination).response { response in
    //            print(response)

    if response.error == nil, let imagePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
        self.mjImage.image = image
        print("imagePath   =     \(imagePath)")
    }
}
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4CE55219-8244-4021-B113-1BB00B8F5B10/Documents/42535.jpg
```

I want that file to a custom folder, if it is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

The Output what i get is,

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4CE55219-8244-4021-B113-1BB00B8F5B10/Documents/42535.jpg

Answer (score 1):

[Append Path Component](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1417069-appendingpathcomponent)

just simply change

```
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("42535.jpg")
```

to

```
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("/yourFolder/42535.jpg")
```

**EDIT**

You can load this image with this function:

```
func loadImageFromDocumentDirectory(nameOfImage : String, folder: String) -> UIImage {
        let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
        if let dirPath = paths.first{
            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("\(folder)/\(nameOfImage)")
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (imageURL.path)) {
                if let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
                    return image
                }

            }
        }
        //Load default image if img doesnt exist. 
        return UIImage.init(named: "something.jpg")!
    }
```

Just simply use it like:

```
imageView.image = loadImageFromDocumentDirectory(nameOfImage : "42535.jpg", folder: "yourFolder")
```

Comment: But how can i see that file in iPhone.

Comment: Its showing nil Image, and the folder I'm not able to track it.

Comment: Test it with simulator, because you can find your simulated device's files on your mac

Comment: That i was getting earlier, but how to show that file in iPhone

Comment: You cant find that file on iPhone, you just can load it with codes, as I wrote earlier.

Comment: Is there a way to add that to phone, because in our app there is a tableview with list and a download button at the bottom. So that the downloaded items can be seen in iPhone

Comment: I dont understand what you would like to do

Comment: Actually there a list of assignments in Tableview, With the download button down, the user can download that particular assignment.

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean with "So that the downloaded items can be seen in iPhone"?

Comment: As u can see from The Picture there is a download button, how will the user know whether the file is downloaded or not, how can he view them